# How to check if an object passed is the correct object in Java

Tags: java, error-handling, runtime

Okay, so I've created this copycat constructor for a ChangeJar object. This object simply stores the Quarters, Dimes, Nickels, and Pennies of an amount passed as a parameter. Such as, ChangeJar(1.29) or ChangeJar("1.29") would result in 5 Quarters, 1 Nickel, and 4 Pennies stored as private instance variables.

Now my copycat constructor is designed to duplicate the properties of one ChangeJar object to another ChangeJar object.

```
public ChangeJar(ChangeJar other){
    this.Quarters = other.Quarters;
    this.Nickels = other.Nickels;
    this.Dimes = other.Dimes;
    this.Pennies = other.Pennies;
}
```

I'm trying to insert an error throwing exception before it copies the content of one changejar to the "other" changejar object.

```
if(Object.getQuarters==null){
    throw new IllegalArguementException();
```

It's to make sure the user does not pass a different object other than a changeJar into the copycat Constructor. I'm not sure on a good way handle this problem in the project.

Comment: Given the definition of the constructor, the compiler will make sure it receives an object of class `ChangeJar`. I don't see where your problem is...could you clarify?

Comment: Also, please respect the naming conventions. Variables start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: How do you expect `Object.getQuarters==null` work? Do you try to check that object have such method? If so, Java is statically typed language. Compiler do the check for you.

Comment: It is really unclear what you're asking. If you could just write a few lines from your your main() class, it would be clearer